# SQL Server Stored Procedure: Read data from URL text file

Tags: sql-server, http, stored-procedures, text, text-files

I am new to SQL Server and wanted to write a stored procedure that takes the data from this URL:

https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy.en-US.txt

Which looks as follows:

```
  # Google_Product_Taxonomy_Version: 2015-02-19
    Animals & Pet Supplies
    Animals & Pet Supplies > Live Animals
    Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies
    Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies
    Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories
    Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories > Bird Cage Bird Baths
```

and insert it into a table:

```
TABLEA (id, text)
```

where `id` is auto generated.

I know how to do the insertion portion however I do not know how to read and parse data in the stored procedure from outside URLs pointing to text files. I am suspecting It can somehow be loaded into a 'temp table' with a single column.

Do not know if this is even possible or I would need to handle the "read" portion in C#, looking for some guidance....

Comment: You should look into SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services). The whole point of SSIS is for dealing with data to and from other systems including files.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange, adding new tech will not be an option. Have to solve this with SQL Server Stored Procs or within C#. If the community here agrees that this cannot be handled within SQL Server Stored Procedure. Maybe because it cannot connect to http, or cannot access http paths, or cannot parse external text files, then ill have to write some kind of C# call that will pass this in this text collection as a stored proc parm.

Comment: By far the best way to handle this is with SSIS. If that is not an option then you would have to utilize something like C# to grab the file and read it.

Comment: Ok cool it looks like i can have SSIS

Comment: looks like i can utilize this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-2-adding-and-configuring-a-flat-file-connection-manager
Dont know yet how the code will look like but will check the link

Comment: Yes indeed that is what you want to use. Glad you are able to use SSIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use xp_cmdshell command on your server? If you use, you can use it with shell command to download the file to local first

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bitsadmin /transfer wcb /priority high https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy.en-US.txt f:\test.txt'
```